# Issue installing a package in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. Trying to install the package UsingR but running into problems:

```
library(UsingR,lib="C:\[whereitwent]") 
Loading required package: HistData 
Error: package ‘HistData’ could not be loaded 
In addition: Warning message: In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) : there is no package called ‘HistData’
```

Now when I did the `install.packages("UsingR", lib="C:\[whereitwent]")` bit, there was a weird part:

```
Warning: unable to move temporary installation ‘C:[where it went]\library\file7946ce71334\acepack’ to ‘C:\[whereitwent]\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\library\acepack’ package ‘HistData’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

I was having this same problem yesterday except instead of "there is no package called 'HistData' it was telling me there is no package called 'Formula'. I uninstalled and reinstalled R Portable this morning, tried again, and this is the result. My professor did this exact thing on her computer right in front of me yesterday and everything worked fine. I've tried this on two computers myself and it's the same issue both places. I've tried googling this but can't find anything substantive, and frankly I'm not really even sure how to google this exact issue. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Note: `"[whereitwent]"` is my edit here so I'm not showing off my whole thing including my name. Everything else is copied and pasted exactly as is.

Comment: @Roland Which is even more ironic given his nom de plume. :D

Comment: Ah thanks! I think I got it. Is there another one I'm missing?

Comment: Weird. Seems like a privacy issue.

Comment: @Roland Done. Still hilarious though. :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to permissions issues, run R or RStudio as administrator (assuming you're on windows) and re-install the package.

If you are unable to run as administrator you usually will not be able to write to the `C:\Program Files` directory on a corporate computer. All you need to do is change the directory to which the package is installing to a folder to which you have read write permissions. For example, on my computer:

```
install.packages("gdata", lib = "C:/Users/mkemp6/Desktop/Rscrap", repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/")
```

To view permissions on a specific folder, right click the folder, select the "Security" tab and and highlight your username.

Comment: Thanks. I am on Windows, but I'm on my work computer. Does this mean any time I want to install a package on R on my work computer, I have to have the IT guy come over and run R as him?

Comment: Nope, navigate to R or RStudio in the file explorer or program menu from the start menu and right click. There will be a list of options with one being "Run as administrator" with a tiny shield next to it.

Comment: I should mention that I'm on Windows XP. Here's what I see:
So I click Run As...
http://i.imgur.com/rZpCTGP.jpg

And I get this. The admin username requires a password (which I don't have). The only other option is my default username which I'm logged into the computer under.
http://i.imgur.com/dm3bhih.jpg

Comment: @dickscraper please view my edit to the answer above

Comment: Thanks. Before your comment, I went ahead and installed R Portable on my thumb drive, thinking surely I have all necessary permissions there. I ran R and made sure my .libpaths() directed to the thumb drive. I then installed UsingR to a new folder within the thumb drive. Same issue:

> library("UsingR", lib=[thumb drive])
Loading required package: Hmisc
Loading required package: Formula
Error: package ‘Formula’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called ‘Formula’

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to install packages, this will set library path:

```
.libPaths('C:/[path]')
```

you might need to escape the slashes, I'm sorry I don't use windows. You can add this to a file .Rprofile in your home folder and you won't have to do it again.

Alternatively (or in concert) you may want to look at the packrat package which will install packages with the project you're working on

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was solved by updating R to 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar issue on my Ubuntu machine. I solved it by running R as a "sudo" user and then install the packages from CRAN.